# How to call a function on a child component only when the parent component returns an observable using Angular4

Tags: angular, observable

"In a nutshell: make one HTTP request and pass that data to all components. The issue is that the other components run before I get the response back from the initial HTTP request. All components are just extracting bits of data from the HTTP response object" - Using Angular 4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Basically, my parent component calls a service that loads my JSON. within the service method, I assign the response from my HTTP request to an Observable using rxjs BehaviorSubject so that I can access and follow from all my components that are subscribed to it. Figured I could just make one call to my server and just grab the parts I want throughout all my components instead of making many calls to the server. Maybe I am going at this all wrong...most likely am.

MY Parent componenet:

```
constructor(private _service: ProductsService, private data:DataService) { 
   this.getCatgegories(this.masterProduct);
}
```

My Service method:

```
private productCategoriesList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
currentList = this.productCategoriesList.asObservable();

changeCatList(categoriesList){
   this.productCategoriesList.next(categoriesList);
}

getCatgegories(masterProduct: number) {
  return this.http
    .get(this.url)
    .map(response => {
    let productArray = response.json()[0].products;
    let henry = this.getFields(productArray, 'product');
    this.changeCatList(henry);
    //some parsing of object to get the returned value

    return catObj;
    });
}
```

Comment: are you having some trouble somewhere, it's not clear what the problem is ;)

Comment: can you add the HTML template as well? if possible create a plunker

Comment: I tried to simplify my question. Just want to make one HTTP request call and be able to access that response from any of my components so i am not making several HTTP request calls. I have my app working not with the above code but the issue is that i am making multiple HTTP requests calls for the same data and just parsing it differently.

Comment: Here is a link to the working app: http://travismichael.net/dist/

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is you are in right approach. In case you want to notify all the component who ever subscribe to your service is the good way to handle data from server as per your requirement.

This approach will also work where components are not parent child, so it will work for all.

You can also think of `@Input` and `@Output` if its parent child and emit and event on change and cat catch them in other component. But your approach works good in large number of component.

#### your approach and correction.

In your service you are exposing 2 observable which can be subscribed. As `getCatgegories(masterProduct: number)` is returning an observable you can subscribe to it and get data like below

so change your service to check if data is available then return or else make a call to the service.

```
   // check if the method is called once then directly get the value from `BehavourSubject` or else call the method to get the data.
private productCategoriesList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
currentList = this.productCategoriesList.asObservable();

changeCatList(categoriesList){
   this.productCategoriesList.next(categoriesList);
}

getCatgegories(masterProduct: number) {
  const availableData = undefined;
  this.currentList.subscribe((data) => {
   if(data !==[]) { availableData  = data; }
  });

  if(availableData !== undefined ) {
    return this.http
    .get(this.url)
    .map(response => {
    let productArray = response.json()[0].products;
    let henry = this.getFields(productArray, 'product');
    this.changeCatList(henry);
    //some parsing of object to get the returned value

    return catObj;
    });
    } else {
      return this.currentList;
    } 
}
```

#### Solution to your problem

```
constructor(private _service: ProductsService, private data:DataService) { 
   this.ProductsService.getCatgegories(this.masterProduct).subscribe(( data) => {
      // do some operation into data
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Got pulled to a work lunch. Will give it a shot when I get back in about 2 hours.

Comment: this.changeList(henry) is where I am defining the Observable that I want to pass to all my components that are subscribed to it. So this will now work cause it is asking if the availableData exist before it was even created if that makes sense. I am not wanting to return the productCategoriesList form the getCategories function. Just assigning the initial response to the HTTP request to productCategoriesList.

Comment: `currentList` this holds the value in observable, so either you subscribe it or call the method to get vaue I think