# How to trigger a callback on home page, when some menu button is clicked

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to figure out how to trigger a callback on home page in ionic 3
when a menu button is clicked? What are the options?

Comment: you can look into this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852456/how-to-call-a-function-on-a-child-component-only-when-the-parent-component-retur/46852995#46852995

Comment: What does this answer have to do with my question? In a menu there is a bunch of buttons and then when clicked i the home page (which is set as the root page) needs to execute some logic like fetching data. The answer you suggest has to do with Observable and http request listening.

Comment: you can setup `Observable` type variable in service and subscribe it in the root component and on change of it  or `.subscribe.next()` you can do some processing. you can also achieve this by `@Output` variable but for the `@Output` variable parent and child relation of the components are needed. so the observable solution is better one I think

Comment: this works Thank You ionic also introduces the option of Events

Comment: which one you choose, `@Output` or `Observable` ? let me post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach this problem in 2 ways

#### Observable

you can setup Observable type variable in service and subscribe it in the root component and on change of it or `.subscribe.next()` you can do some processing.

#### @Output - for event trigger

you can also achieve this by `@Output` variable but for the `@Output` variable parent and child relation of the components are needed.

So so the `observable` solution is better if there is not parent and child possible. Or else you can simply add `@Output` variable and trigger an event.

Comment: I tried using [link Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) from ionic
I also tried observable

Comment: if your header component is inside app component you can also try `@Output`

Comment: doesn't seems to work with output since menu is not a child of home page
i guess i would stay with Observable Thank You